# ScaryBug Tutorial extra argument in title call

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, cocoa

I'm trying to do a tutorial I found online and I cannot for the life of me get rid of this error. Simple code but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please see screenshot.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ouddrdt7k5ls89/Screenshot%202015-07-02%2019.37.04.png?dl=0

edit: Additional screenshot of model
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x23qnxml6vo3k4p/Screenshot%202015-07-02%2020.17.36.png?dl=0

Thank you

Comment: just delete "title:" - the first argument in the function does not need a name

Comment: I didn't have any luck doing that. Thank you though.

Comment: please show a picture or paste the code of your ScaryDocBug class(.Swift file), so we can have a look what you got in your init method there

Comment: Here is a shot of the model if that will help. Thank you.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x23qnxml6vo3k4p/Screenshot%202015-07-02%2020.17.36.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is a really silly one and easy to miss, you have declared the class twice. This is your code:

```
class ScaryBugDoc : NSObject {
     class ScaryBugDoc: NSObject {
          // Your implementation is here.
     }
}
```

Just simply change it to a single class definition

Comment: smh. That just happened. Thank you Manav Gabhawala.